# Function triggered many times when mouse wheel even triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a single page and single section website. there is a pagination on that section that will change the page when the mouse scrolled up/down.

I've tried to implement mousewheel event but the event triggered many times not only one time, it changes my page number many time on one scroll down/up event.
I've check scroll and mouse wheel event but each of it always trigger the event not only one time but it's triggered many time on one scroll event

```js
var page = 1;
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    $('#page-number').html(page++);
    console.log('Scroll up');
  } else {
    $('#page-number').html(page--);
    console.log('Scroll down');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Page <span id="page-number">1</span></div>
```

I expect the page only change one time when the mouse scroll up/down not many times.

Comment: The event is triggered more than once, that is how it works. Look into debounce

Answer (score 2):

You can use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#debounce) or [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#throttle) functions from [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/).

Example:

```js
let page = 1;

const mouseWheelHandler = (event) => {
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    $('#page-number').html(page++);
    console.log('Scroll up');
  } else {
    $('#page-number').html(page--);
    console.log('Scroll down');
  }
}

// will be called in a half of second after user stops to scroll
$(window).bind('mousewheel', _.debounce((event) => mouseWheelHandler(event), 500));

// will be called once in a second while user keeps scrolling
// $(window).bind('mousewheel', _.throttle((event) => mouseWheelHandler(event)), 1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div>Page <span id="page-number">1</span></div>
```

Comment: it takes too long using 500ms to change my website page

Answer (score 0):

```js
var page = 1;
var currentDirection;

$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
  if (currentDirection !== 'up' && event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    currentDirection = 'up';
    $('#page-number').html(page++);
    console.log('Scroll up');
  } else if (currentDirection !== 'down') {
    currentDirection = 'down';
    $('#page-number').html(page--);
    console.log('Scroll down');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Page <span id="page-number">1</span></div>
```